# Как ведет себя static метод в многопоточном приложении?

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Например тут:

```
public class Singleton{

    private static Cat cat = new Cat();

    public static Cat getInstance(){

           return cat;
    }
}
```

Почему такой вариант хуже (если хуже), чем использование не статического метода getInstance()?

P.S. Цель вопроса выяснить, есть ли разница между использованием статического метода getInstance() и не статического, в ситуации когда к нему могут обращаться много потоков одновременно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Приведённый вариант лучше, чем вариант с нестатическим getInstance потому, что иначе никак. Если метод нестатический, то придётся создавать класс Singleton каждый раз. Кроме того, очевидно, что вы неправильно реализовали синглтон. Получается, что вы можете получать экземпляр класса Cat через Singleton, а можете просто создавать через new Cat сколько угодно, что будет неверно и вы никак не сможете от этого защититься. Поэтому надо делать

```
public class Cat {

    private static final Cat cat = new Cat();

    public static Cat getInstance(){
           return cat;
    }
}
```

С точки зрения многопоточности нет разницы между статическим и нестатическим методом, если он не помечен как synchronized.

Приведённый выше вариант, как уже говорилось, имеет недостаток: создание экземпляра при подгрузке класса (часто при старте приложения). Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, можно использовать паттерн Initialization on Demand Holder idiom.

```
public class Cat{
        private Cat() {
        }

        private static class LazyHolder {
                private static final Cat INSTANCE = new Cat();
        }

        public static final Cat getInstance() {
                return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

При таком раскладе достигается эффективная потокобезопасность и получена ленивая инициализация (lazy-load singleton).

Однако, в большинстве случаев нет необходимости делать такую сложную конструкцию, а достаточно реализовать первым способом.

Comment: Мне кажется, что еще надо конструктор сделать приватным.

Answer (score 9):

Я смотрю тут дискуссия свелась к обсуждению паттерна singleton :)

Собственно, если отвечать на вопрос "***Как ведет себя static метод в многопоточном приложении?***" нужно знать следующее:

1) Из static метода доступны только static поля и методы, поэтому проблемы могут возникнуть только с ними (или еще с передаваемыми в метод параметрами и объектами, сохраненными в локальных переменных, но это уже не зависит от использования static), а если точнее - при *записи* в static поля. В приведенном примере запись в такое поле производится лишь однажды - при загрузке класса.

2) Использование synchronized static метода абсолютно равносильно использованию объекта класса как мьютекса. Следующие два метода работают идентично:

```
class Example{
    static void foo(){
        synchronized(Example.class){
            //method body
        }
    }
    synchronized static void bar(){
        //method body
    }
}
```

3) Без использования synchronized в методе или с методом вызов его кода **никак** не отличается в плане многопоточности от вызова обыкновенного метода.

Напоследок предложу еще один способ реализации паттерна singleton, на мой взгляд весьма изящный и эффективный - никаких проблем с инициализацией/многопоточностью

```
enum Singleton{
   Instance;
  //methods
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Метод getInstance в реализации паттерна Singleton может быть только статическим. Потому что это основная идея паттерна: объект должен быть только один и должен быть доступен из любого класса нашего приложения. В такой реализации паттерна не возникнет никаких проблем с многопоточностью, потому что операция модификации здесь только new Cat(), которая будет вызвана только один раз. Другой вопрос, что такая реализация паттерна  хороша только если

1. Вы абсолютно уверены, что в конструкторе не может быть исключения
2. Вам неважно то, что инициализация происходит при запуске приложения, а не в момент первого обращения

Действительно, многие синглтоны имеют пустой или простой и быстроисполняемый конструктор. Тогда эти два пункта можно не учитывать. Но иногда разработчик всё-таки заинтересован в ленивой загрузке и проверке на исключения. Проблемы возникают тогда, когда метод getInstance выглядит так:

```
public static Cat getInstance(){
       if (cat == null) cat = new Cat();
       return cat;
}
```

Здесь действительно будут проблемы с многопоточностью. Поэтому для любых неатомарных операций стоит использовать модификатор synchronized. Иначе мы не сможем гарантировать, что объект Cat создаться лишь один раз. Если есть желание хорошо разобраться с многопоточностью в Java, советую прочитать [Java Concurrency](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) и [мануал](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) на сайте Oracle.

Comment: Почему, метод getInstance() может быть только статический, позволю себе не согласиться . Что нам мешает написать : 
<code> Cat tom = new Singleton().getInstance() </code>  
Я наверное издалека зашел, цель моего вопроса выяснить, есть ли разница между использованием статического метода getInstance() и не статического, в ситуации когда к нему могут обращаться много потоков одновременно. У меня есть подозрение что это не дело вкуса.

Comment: Действительно, там же обертка. А synchronized/volatile в ваших двух примерах используются? Cat - с изменяемыми полями, setters? Не static методы помещаются в кучу, heap, и имеют свою копию контекста. Static вызывается напрямую. Какие там еще, интересно, могут быть отличия. Может быть, это связано с тем, что volatile стал хорошо работать только с Java 1.5. Или автору могла понадобиться возможность переопределять метод getInstance.

Comment: "Что нам мешает написать :   Cat tom = new Singleton().getInstance() " - это полное безумие так делать. Тогда зачем вообще это нужно, если каждый и так может делать new Singleton везде где хочется? Посмотрите же наконец сначала как синглтоны делаются, а уже потом думайте о многопоточности. И никакой synchronized/volatile тут не нужен.

Comment: "Поэтому для любых неатомарных операций стоит использовать модификатор synchronized" - не всегда верно

Comment: Это не синглтон Майерса. Тут я назвал класс-контейнер Singleton, а класс, объект которого мы получаем-Cat, не случайно, выражение "new Singleton()" не вернет нам новый объект типа Cat, синглтон я взял просто как пример (возможно не очень удачно). Если проверять в один поток , то статический getInstance() быстрее чем не статический, действительно , на создание нового (даже простого)объекта Singleton уходит время, но в мн.поточном варианте сравнить их нет возможности. Если к статическому методу getInstance() обратятся 200 потоков одновременно не повлияет ли его статичность на производительность

Comment: Но вроде бы не влияет...)

Comment: Не может повлиять. Как вообще по вашему статичность метода может влиять на concurrency? Откуда вообще эта мысль взялась? :) Машинный код, который будет сгенерирован будет мало отличаться для статического метода от обычного с поправкой разве что на this. Никакие блокировки при этом не берутся и манипуляции с кэшами не осуществляются.